# What is styled component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I recently heard that there is a component called styled component in ReactJS. This question was asked me during one of my interview.

If anyone has an idea, kindly explain.

Comment: Its a library for react. Do a google search.

Comment: I understand there is a library called styled-components. But there is a specific concept called styled component in React which I am unable to find googling.

Comment: I never mind taking negative votes for my question but I only need answer. This is to people who down voted.

Comment: The question in the interview was "I heard that there is a component"? What are you exactly asking here?

Comment: its already there in my question i.e., what is styled component in reactjs?

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally you'd do the styling of your react app using css or a preprocessor like SASS or LESS. An alternative, that is becoming more popular recently, is to place the styling of your components within your JS.

Styled Components is one of the many packages that enable you to do this: https://www.styled-components.com/

Other examples include cssinjs: http://cssinjs.org/ or glamorous: https://glamorous.rocks/